# Is there a xsd file for "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" namespace?

Tags: c#, xsd, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I want to create / infer schema for data-contract serialized classes.

When I use `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` attribute the serializer is injecting attributes `z:Id="i2"` and `z:Ref="i2"` to reference the same object instances.
Both attributes are from `http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/` namespace.

**Questions**:

- Is there a xsd schema file for the namespace used by serializer which I could import into my schema?
- For now I am defining those attributes as a `xs:ID` / `xs:IDREF` pair. Is that correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The xsd schema is supposed to described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733112.aspx) - look for the section Data Contract Serialization Schema. However, if you do look for your attributes, you will not find them in there - documentation bug!

To get the full schema, take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff386135%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh627685%28v=office.12%29.aspx) - inside the WSDL types, you'll find the correct schema. As for your assumption regarding the attributes, yes, you are correct.

I am inlining it here, just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
    <xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI"/>
    <xs:element name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
    <xs:element name="boolean" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean"/>
    <xs:element name="byte" nillable="true" type="xs:byte"/>
    <xs:element name="dateTime" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
    <xs:element name="decimal" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
    <xs:element name="double" nillable="true" type="xs:double"/>
    <xs:element name="float" nillable="true" type="xs:float"/>
    <xs:element name="int" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:element name="long" nillable="true" type="xs:long"/>
    <xs:element name="QName" nillable="true" type="xs:QName"/>
    <xs:element name="short" nillable="true" type="xs:short"/>
    <xs:element name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="unsignedByte" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
    <xs:element name="unsignedInt" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
    <xs:element name="unsignedLong" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
    <xs:element name="unsignedShort" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
    <xs:element name="char" nillable="true" type="tns2:char"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="char">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="duration" nillable="true" type="tns2:duration"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="duration">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
            <xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?"/>
            <xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns2:guid"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="guid">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:attribute name="FactoryType" type="xs:QName"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Ref" type="xs:IDREF"/>
</xs:schema>
```